# Push Notifications on the mozilla firefox addon

Tags: firefox, push-notification, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

I am developing a mozilla firefox addon and I need my addon to show up the notifications on my addon icon as numbers if some data in the server changed. What should I do in the server and in firefox addon for support this kind of notifications?

For Example, Firebug shows the number of errors in the console as badge icon on the addon as a notification. I also need that kind of notification. Could anyone help please?

I reffered the below pages 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Simple_Push_API
http://mozilla-push-service.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

and I couldn't get the clear point. Correct me if am in the wrong way.

Comment: It seems you're asing to different questions here. First, in order to implement a badge icon see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#Badged_buttons Last, about the push notifications stuff: notice that you don't need them. You can make the same by other means: polling an url every N seconds or minutes or connecting to a websocket server and reacting to its messages.